# Can I bind double Shift key to keyboard layout change?

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, shortcuts

As a vim user, I would like to set my keyboard layout change binding to something convenient so I don't have to move my palms from the normal position. I used to use `CapsLock` for this purpose but recently changed it's binding to `Ctrl`. So I would like to set keyboard layout change action binding to fast double `Shift` key or something like that. Is that possible in Ubuntu?

Comment: Look here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/141729/custom-key-to-toggle-keyboard-layout/317653